# Welcome to Prison

Tags: riddle

> Welcome to the prison!
>
> You're here to have fun, so get into your cell.
>
> Make sure to get into the right one, just check with the other
>   inmates, to be sure.
>
> You will be in one of the 9 zones, north, east, south, west, north-east,
>   north-west, south-east, south-west or central.
>
> Stay in the correct zone, and try to be unique.
>
> All of your inmates are rational, so sort things out with them - If you come into conflict with them, that will really mess things up.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This appears to be about

> **a Sudoku puzzle entry**

Welcome to the prison!
You're here to have fun, so get into your cell.

> Every number belongs in its own cell, and Sudoku puzzles are fun!

Make sure to get into the right one, just check with the other inmates, to be sure.

> You need to be in the correct cell with respect to the location of the other numbers in the nearby cells.

You will be in one of the zones, north, east, south, west, north-east, north-west, south-east, south-west or central.

> There are 9 zones in a Sudoku puzzle, as listed here.

Stay in the correct zone, and try to be unique.

> You need to be the only (unique) one with your number in your zone.

All of your inmates are rational, so sort things out with them - If you come into conflict with them, that will really mess things up.

> All the numbers are integers so of course are also rational.  You must not conflict with any of the other numbers - no duplicates in a row, column or zone are allowed.

Comment: Perfect answer well done! I don't know how you can solve this quickly...

Comment: @Melkor a grid of nine cells + uniqueness + no conflicts with neighbours + rational numbers. I had the same thought, but didn't get to the site until just now, so I'm late. :(

Comment: Yeah, I had it at line 4 and just had to read the rest to confirm. The nine zones' arrangement was a pretty good giveaway. :)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of minesweeper.

Comment: @Benjamin, but what about the zones?

Comment: I was thinking of a magical square. But then, a sudoku is only a special case of a magical square.

Comment: I was picturing 'Hollywood Squares'!